# MPMoviePlayerViewController dismisses immediately

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am playing a movie via:

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:asset.filepath]];

//[[vc moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
[self presentViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The controller shows up but immediately after, dismisses itself. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure MPMoviePlayerViewController dismisses gracefully and not crashing? Did you checked the vide which you want to play?

Comment: @Deepesh Yes, it's a mov file recorded from iPhone. I played it in Quicktime and it played just fine. I don't see any logs of it crashing. It simply displays and dismisses itself immediately revealing the view controller that displayed it.

Answer (score 2):

you have to remove `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` `NSNotificationCenter` like :-

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:asset.filepath]];

//[[vc moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:moviePlayer  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer.moviePlayer];
[self presentViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Becouse `MPMoviePlayerViewController` automatically registers itself to the `NSNotificationCenter` upon creation. You have to first remove this registration and it will stop dismissing itself automatically. Hope its helps you

**Please check Bellow Link:-**

http://josebolanos.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/dismissing-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-the-right-way/

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue while trying to play audio. Try setting your movie player as a property with a strong reference.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{` method, if you are `dismissing` your `moviePlayer` then this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

" To present a movie player view controller modally, you typically use the `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:` method. This method is part of a category on the `UIViewController` class and is implemented by the Media Player framework. The `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:` method presents a movie player view controller using the standard transition animations for presenting video content. To dismiss a modally presented movie player view controller, call the `dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated`
method."

You can't use the normal modal presentation method. Must use the method provided by media player framework in `UIViewContoller` category.